# jQuery wrap each two labels in a div

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to wrap each two labels in a div.These labels are parents of a input radio type button and I want to target them like parents of the input radio type, to avoid wrapping any other existing labels on my website (probably there's a better way to target these labels) . Here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lqu8rcLb/2/

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
<dl>
<dd>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio1">
  </label>
   <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="radio2">
   </label>
</dd>
</dl>      
      <br></br>
<dd>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio3">
  </label>
   <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="radio4">
   </label>
</dd>
</dl>       
</fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('input:radio').parent().each(function () {
  $(this).wrapAll("<div class="wrapped-labels"></div>");
});
```

But the jQuery code is not working and I tried many other possibilities , the closest one was to wrap each label in a div, but this is not what I want as I want both labels in one div.

Comment: `"<div class="wrapped-labels"></div>"` Double quotes used in a string in double quotes would create issues. You want to make the internal quotes single or escape them with `\`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that.But as i said it wraps each label,not both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to get only one of the labels, then add the sibling labels to the collection, *then* wrap in a div

```
$('#myform label:has(input[type="radio"]) + label:has(input[type="radio"])').each(function() {
    $(this).add($(this).siblings('label')).wrapAll('<div class="wrapped-labels"></div>')
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqu8rcLb/3/)

Another way to do it, would be

```
$('input[type="radio"]').parent().each(function() {
    if ( ! $(this).closest('.wrapped-labels').length )
        $(this).add($(this).siblings('label')).wrapAll('<div class="wrapped-labels"></div>');
});
```

Comment: Quick and useful.Thanks a lot. Any advice on how should i include for input type checkbox too? Or i should simply repeat this code and edit the part with type="radio" with type="checkbox"?

Comment: I like both of them but i think i'll go with the first one :) .

Comment: Do you really need to check the type, and is there any way you can reverse it, as in exclude text inputs -> `[type!="text"]` etc. Otherwise, the second one is probably easiest to extend to checkboxes -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Lqu8rcLb/4/**

Comment: Well,i have other types of forms with label and select inside them plus input type text etc,so yes i think is better to check the type.